# Fail install marmap package on R v3.2.4

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install the packages on R v3.2.4 from GitHub, and even after installing Rcpp I keep getting an error:

```
install_github("marmap","ericpante")
Skipping install of 'marmap' from a github remote, the SHA1 (3e62fc8d) has not changed since last install.
  Use 'force = TRUE' to force installation
Warning message:
Username parameter is deprecated. Please use ericpante/marmap
```

Any idea of what the possible problem might be? Should I downgrade R to run it or there is a better option?

PS. running on OSX 10.12.1 (Sierra)

Comment: Sounds like the package might already be installed? What happens when you run `library(marmap)`.

Comment: Have you tried installing from one of the CRAN servers? The only difference between the current CRAN version (v0.95) and the github one (v0.96) is a minor bug correction.

Answer (score 0):

> library(marmap)

Attaching package: 'marmap'

The following object is masked from 'package:grDevices':

```
as.raster
```